# How can i use default value on postgres when query include null value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgres and I've integration app which write data to database. My column should not be null but my app send null value. I tried to set default value but query override this rule with null value. How can i handle this change without code.

My Column configuration looks like this.

[image: Column Definition]

[image: Constraints]

Comment: You cannot change that without code. Write a trigger.

Comment: Can you share any example or reference ?

Comment: That wouldn't answer your question. Perhaps you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you won't or can't change the query in code, you have to use trigger
2. If you can change code structure and query:

   - If the column has a default value, then no need to send `NULL` value to query

   ```sql
   -- Before change
   insert into your_table (id, name, default_col) values 
   (1, 'name', null);

   -- After change (remove null data)
   insert into your_table (id, name) values 
   (1, 'name');
   ```

   - Or send default value in insert query

   ```sql
   -- Before change
   insert into your_table (id, name, default_col) values 
   (1, 'name', null);

   -- After change (Use default keyboard)
   insert into your_table (id, name, default_col) values 
   (1, 'name', default);
   ```